# How to short Facebook X-path

Tags: python, xpath

I want to short that xpath. So how I'm going to do that?

**What x-path function can I use?**

```
*//div[@class='rq0escxv l9j0dhe7 du4w35lb j83agx80 cbu4d94t pfnyh3mw d2edcug0 ri2l8tne ph5uu5jm b3onmgus gloz99to r516eku6 k83vx86k']//div//span[@class='a8c37x1j ni8dbmo4 stjgntxs l9j0dhe7 ltmttdrg g0qnabr5'][normalize-space()='Join Group']*
```

shorter form:

`//span[contains(text(),'Join Group')]`

I want that kind of short form.

[Here is the GitHub link for more precise understanding.](https://github.com/ImJawadHossain/MiracleExperiments/blob/master/2.FacebookGroupJoinBot.py)

Comment: Good Question but you have to write more clear discription.

Comment: its look more precius.

Comment: I want to write more precise x-path.

Comment: //span[contains(text(),'Join Group')] is a goo approch use @class and other function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use basic x path function :

```
//span[contains(text(),'your text')]

//span[@role='button' and normalize-space() = 'your text']
```

this might help your case.